# pass callback to class

Tags: c#, delegates

I have a class in which I would like to store a function call.  This function call can be invoked by the class but set by the parent class.  I would like to externally supply the call to be made, including any parameters.

Something like...

```
public class TestDelegate
{
    public TestDelegate()
    {
        TestClass tc = new TestClass(DoSomething("blabla", 123, null));
    }

    private void DoSomething(string aString, int anInt, object somethingElse)
    {
        ...
    }
}

public class TestClass
{
    public TestClass(delegate method)
    {
        this.MethodToCall = method;
        this.MethodToCall.Execute();
    }

    public delegate MethodToCall { get; set; }
}
```

When the `TestClass` class is initialized it will call the DoSomething method of the parent class with the specified parameters.  I should also mention that I do not want to require the same method signature for the method called.  Meaning not always (string, int, object)

Comment: So what is your question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `Action` delegate type and create an instance of this from a closure:

```
public class TestClass
{
    public TestClass(Action method)
    {
        MethodToCall = method;
        method();
    }

    public Action MethodToCall { get; set; }
}

public class TestDelegate
{
    public TestDelegate()
    {
        // Uses lambda syntax to create a closure that will be represented in
        // a delegate object and passed to the TestClass constructor.

        TestClass tc = new TestClass(() => DoSomething("blabla", 123, null));
    }

    private void DoSomething(string aString, int anInt, object somethingElse)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: you were 36 seconds faster ... *grrr* :P

Answer (score 3):

`delegate` isn't the name of a type - it's a keyword used to *declare* delegate types, and also anonymous methods.

I suspect you *actually* want a specific type of delegate, such as [`Action`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action.aspx), which is a delegate with no parameters and a void return type. You'll then need to change your calling code as well - because currently you're *calling* `DoSomething` before you call the constructor. Sample:

```
public class TestDelegate
{
    public TestDelegate()
    {
        TestClass tc = new TestClass(() => DoSomething("blabla", 123, null));
    }

    private void DoSomething(string aString, int anInt, object somethingElse)
    {
        ...
    }
}

public class TestClass
{
    public TestClass(Action method)
    {
        this.MethodToCall = method;
        this.MethodToCall.Invoke();
    }

    // Do you really need this to be writable?
    public Action MethodToCall { get; set; }
}
```